# Progress bar position issue in android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Progress bar position isn't proper in Feed screen.

App version: 1.0.21

[image]

Comment: Down voters, please care to leave a comment!

Comment: I was about to post this as well, it has happened to me on my tablet and phone (Huawei Ascend G510 (running Android 4.1.1) and  Nexus 7 2013 (running Android 4.3))

Comment: @PareshMayani Don't expect that. Their brains are only able to click on down arrow. They're unable to write anything nor to use keyboard. BTW: Downvoting proven bug is an extreme stupidity, I must admit.

Comment: @trejder seriously this is a serious issue! People should try to at least look at the output snap or at least try to read and re-produce the steps mentioned (if any given).

Comment: I know, that this is serious and that's why I +1. But, I met so strange responses here (mostly completely non-serious to a serious problems), that I wanted to inform you to expect nothing. Maybe my irony was too high, but I just happen to have a bad day...

Comment: @AndrewT. Hope this is not done using any automated script :) Saying because older threads are being marked as duplicate, that's even after a year!

Comment: Uh, no automated script. I saw the issue is more or less the same, and it's no repro due to HNQ on the top. I was struggling to flag as no repro or dupe of that...